# Laravel 4.2 - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I've just started building a Laravel application and came across a problem with routing.

1. Laravel version - 4.2
2. PHP version  - 5.5
3. I'm using XAMPP
4. I have the rewrite module active on Apache

Here is my Routes file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', array(
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'IndexController@index'
));

Route::get('/account', array(
    'as' => 'account',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@get_create'
));
```

My controllers look like this:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index');
    }
}

<?php

class AccountController extends BaseController
{
    public function get_create()
    {
        return 'asd';
    }

    public function post_create()
    {

    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#11 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:5680
#10 Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection:match in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:5004
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Router:findRoute in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:4992
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:4984
#7 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:715
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:696
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:7744
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:8351
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:8298
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:10961
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\bootstrap\compiled.php:657
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in C:\xampp\htdocs\Protosite\public\index.php:49
```

EDIT: One thing I forgot to mention, the index works fine, it's the account page with the error.

I've looked at similar problems but for some reason they have not solved it.

Cheers!

Comment: You should remove the slash in front of `/account`, that is not expected in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your rewriting isn't working. If you add `index.php` to the URL right before the `/account` does it work?

For example, `yourdomain.com/account` would become `yourdomain.com/index.php/account`

If your rewriting isn't working, but you have the `.htaccess` file in your `public` directory, then you probably need to allow overrides in your apache configuration. Here is an example virtual host configuration for XAMPP and Laravel.

I've marked the lines you need to change. Change the first and third to point to the `public` directory in your website's directory. Then change the second line to the domain name you're using with your website.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yourdomain/public"      # Change this line
    ServerName yourdomain.com                             # Change this line
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/yourdomain/public">       # Change this line
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
        AllowOverride All    # This line enables .htaccess files
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need to restart Apache for these settings to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried it, and it works so thank you. If you could give me any pointers on how to get the normal URLs working, that would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have a file in your `public/` directory named `.htaccess`?  

If you don't have the `.htaccess` file you can use the version from the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls).  

That is the file that removes the `index.php` from the URL. For it to work you need to set `AllowOverride All` in the Apache configuration for your website's directory.

Comment: I was using the htaccess that was installed with Laravel, and I also tried the other version on Laravels docs, and still didn't work. However, I've managed to use the `php artisan serve` command, which seems to work okay.

Comment: By default, Apache ignores `.htaccess` files in directories. You need to tell Apache to use the `.htaccess` file. Did you setup a virtual host in apache for your website? If so, could you edit your question and paste your virtual host configuration in there?

Comment: I've added an example virtual host configuration for XAMPP and Laravel to my answer.